# Find the cardinality of the following set?

Tags: cardinals

If I have a set A with |A| = n then what would be the cardinality of the following set?

{ |  ∈ (A), |X| ≤ 1}

What I understand is that this is the set of all X such that it is part of the power set of A and cardinality is less than or equal to 1. Thus I say the cardinality of this set is 2. Because there are two sets: {}, the empty set and {X} which are part of the power set of A.

Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: No.  You are not understanding correctly.  $X \ne \{X\}$ and $\{X\}$ is (probably) not a subset of $A$ and so is not an element of $P(A)$.  And if you think about it if $a,b,c \in A$ then $\{a\}\subset X$ and $|\{a\}| = 1$ and $\{b\}\subset X$ and $|{\a\}|=1$. So $\{a\},\{b\},\emptyset \in \{X|X\in P(A),|X|\le 1\}$ so the cardinality is at least $3$ if $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be have trouble with set notation.  $X$ is a place holder variable that is not any actual set.  It merely means  "Let $X$ be any element of $P(A)$"  which is to say "Let $X$ be any subset of $A$".

So $\{X| X\in P(A); |X| \le 1\} =$ the set of all subsets of $A$ that have a cardinality of at most one.

And the question "what is the cardinality of $\{X| X\in P(A); |X| \le 1\}$" is asking nothing more or less than "how many subsets of $A$ have one or fewer elements".

And the answer to that is obvious.  The empty set is a subset with zero elements, and every set with a single element has one element. And any set with more than one element has a cardinality of more than one. As there are $n$ elements in $A$ there are $n$ sets with a single element.  Adding the empty set we have the cardinality is $n+1$.

Another way of looking at this is:

If $A = \{a_1,a_2,......, a_n\}$ then $\{X| X\in P(A); |X| \le 1\}=\{\emptyset, \{a_1\},\{a_2\},....., \{a_n\}\}$

Answer (score 0):

You have $1$ subset of $A$ of cardinality $0$ (the empty subset).

And you have $n$ subsets of $A$ of cardinality $1$ (each $\lbrace x \rbrace$ for $x \in A$).

So the set of subsets of cardinality at most $1$ has cardinality $$n+1
$$

Comment: so the X represents all elements of A? I am just confused by how { |  ∈ (A) = n. I know that A has n different elements, and for each there is one subset in the powerset, thus n subsets. But what does X represent then? Thanks.

Comment: $X$ is a variable.  It just means an *unspecified* subset of $A$.   If $A={a,b,c}$ so $|A| =3$ then there are $8$ subsets of $A$.  $X$ can be any one of those subsets. $\{X|X\in P(A) ;|X|\le 1\} = \{X| X = \emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},$ or $\{a,b,c\}$ so that $|X|=0$ or $1\}=\{X|X = \emptyset, \{a\},\{b\}, $ or $\{c\}\}= \{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks, makes sense now.